# Android Device Dual Sim number Display

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get sim number that I am using in android devices. I am getting errors in version OREO and Samsung Devices.

```
 btn_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final HintRequest hintRequest =
                    new HintRequest.Builder().setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true).build();

            try {
                final GoogleApiClient googleApiClient =
                        new GoogleApiClient.Builder(GetSimNumber.this).addApi(Auth.CREDENTIALS_API).build();
                final PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                        Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(googleApiClient, hintRequest);
                startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), PHONE_NUMBER_HINT, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I am using HintRequest and Google API

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PHONE_NUMBER_HINT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Credential credential = data.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY);
        String phoneNumber = credential.getId();
        Toast.makeText(this, phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It's working in mostly all devices but getting Error in Oreo Samsung Device. if any suggestion tells me ...Thank you in advance

Comment: What errors are you getting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Device Dual Sim number Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52946457/android-device-dual-sim-number-display)

Comment: I am getting in all other devices as Vivo, MI oreo and naught  error only in Samsung

Answer (score 0):

The HintRequest api provided by google has not fully accomplished its feature and is quite buggy , Its works fine in google devices as said by developers "OEM issue that their pixel or nexus phone working well."

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77884951 .

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/issues/27

Many apps are still using it with handling the exceptional cases with own logic such as myntra verify number feature which is there on the profile page.